# Error when start the postgres service with homebrew using Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I installed postgresql 10 with the classic command:

> brew install postgresql@10

Then I started the service:

> brew services start postgresql@10

The output says:

> Successfully started postgresql@10 (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@10)

but when I run this command:

> brew services

This is what I get:

```
Name          Status  User         Plist
cassandra     stopped              
postgresql    stopped              
postgresql@10 error   username /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@10/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@10.plist
```

It seems that the service in not running correctly. Previously I had another version of Posgresql. It was the version 10 again but installed with the installer offered but the postgresql's webpage. However I should have removed it.

I check with this command to see used ports:

```
lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN
```

and I don't have services using the port 5432 (the default port used by postgresql).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I shared the procedure to investigate further and maybe solve the problem.

1. Check the file `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@10/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@10.plist`. This path is given by the `brew services` command.
2. Open the file and see where the log is written. In my case:

> ```
> <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
> <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@10.log</string>
> ```

3. Look at the log. I my case I saw that there was a file locked, probably by the previous instance of postgresql that didn't release the lock. The restart of my Mac solved the issue.